# How to get total count of div tags inside a div tag using python selenium webdriver

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am testing a script to find the number of div tags inside a div tag, reason to do this...is to get the last div number ( div[last div] ) inside a full path.

full path of div is like :

```
full_path = '//*[@id="main"]/div[2]/div/div # continue line
/div[2]/div[i want the total div count here]/div/ # continue line
div/div[2]/div/div'
```

split the path to 4 section

```
full_path = '//*[@id="main"]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[14]/div/div/div[2]/div/div'

half_path1 = '//*[@id="main"]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]'

half_path_with_slash = '//*[@id="main"]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/'

second_half_path = '/div/div/div[2]/div/div'


print ('going to search')

test_path = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,half_path)))

count = driver.select_list(:id=> 'div').options.count

print ('searching')

print (count) # not working
```

so i tried something like this :

```
    waitof = WebDriverWait(driver = driver, timeout = 9)

    array = [] # to collect the div count

    for i in array:

        test_path = waitof.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,half_path1)))
        print('div loaded')

        test_pathx = driver.find_element_by_xpath(slash_path)
        array.append(text_pathx)
        print ('first loop')
        for i in test_pathx:
            print ('second loop')
            loop_path = driver.find_element_by_xpath(just_path1 +'div[%d]' % (i))
            div_elements.append[i]
            print(div_elements[i])

    awesome_full_path = ('//*[@id="main"]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[%d]
/div/div/div[2]/div/div' % div_elements)
```

its not working please help!!!
if the question is not clear please comment (new here)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you simply want to get count of child `div` nodes of another `div`, you can implement something like below:

```
parent_div = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div")
count_of_divs = len(parent_div.find_elements_by_xpath("./div"))
```

or directly

```
count_of_divs = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div/div"))
```

Note that to select required `div` you should use some [predicate](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xpath/xpath_predicate.htm) to be sure that your XPath is unique

If you want to select *last div child* you can also try

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div/div[last()]")
```

Comment: parent_div = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/').                                                           count_of_divs = len(parent_div.find_elements_by_xpath("./div"))                                     like this ?

Comment: Remove the last slash. It would be better if you provide with the HTML sample for the same

Comment: i didn't get that ? @Andersson

Comment: Here `//*[@id="main"]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/` the last slash is redundant. Also you I advice you not to use XPath generated by some browser tool, but to use your own...

Comment: <div class =" Main">
    <div class ="A">
    <div class ="A">
    <div class ="A">
    <div class ="A">
    <div class ="A">
    <div class ="A">
    .
    .
    may be more (we dont know)
    .
    .
    <div class ="Last"> # need this last div

Comment: So why not just to use `driver.find_element_by_class_name("Last")`?

Comment: all class = A, are the subclass of main and i need to dig deeper like this: //*[@id="main"]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[this is the last sub class]/div/div/div[2]/div/div

Comment: //*[@id="main"]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[last()] how it understand this is the last div ? what if there will be a loading delay ?

Comment: You should clarify a little your goal. You should write XPath for target `div` only - do not use absolute XPath like `//*[@id="main"]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]` or something. In case of delay - use [Implicit/Explicit wait](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits)

Comment: an issue here is the delay time + span on mouseover condition to select the needed element, how to get relative XPath? is there any browser plugin to get that? do you have any suggestion for me ?

Comment: No. I don't use Browser tools and I advice not use them at all. Check some XPath guides (for example, [this one](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)) and write your own

Comment: this is why am doing this, I need the last message forward button to be pressed on WhatsApp web could you help me ?

Comment: In my case it's something like `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="vW7d1"][last()]//span[contains(@class, "selectable-text")]')`. Try it

Comment: i tried this to find the last image but : image = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="vW7d1 _1nHRW"][last()]//div[contains(@class, "_3v3PK")]')'

Comment: What is the *last image*? I see no elements with class `_3v3PK`

Comment: last image in chat, i tried this one and it opens the image, so i find forward btn to click on forward option, is this a correct way ? --- image = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="vW7d1"][last()]//div[contains(@class, "_3v3PK")]') ---(next line)  --- forward_icn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="rAUz7"][3]/div[contains(@title, "Forward")]')---

Comment: `image.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[.="Forward message"]')`